# C# Winform Retry

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a problem with a Retry form. With this Form, I'm able to load a file from the internet. When it's done the main form pops up again. So far so good.

But when the user presses cancel, the save dialog pops up again. But what I want when the user presses the cancel button, he returns to the main form.

It Should be in this part, I think:

```
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
{
    return Result.Cancelled;
}
```

This is a part of my code:

```
try
{
    // Create a form to select objects.
    DialogResult result = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.None;
    while (result == DialogResult.None || result == DialogResult.Retry)
    {
        // Picking Objects.
        if (result == DialogResult.Retry)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog();
            saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Convert.ToString(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
            saveFileDialog1.FileName = "test";
            saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Family Files (*.rfa)|*.rfa|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
            saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                string address = "http://www.autodesk.com/revit-basic-sample-family-2017-enu?_ga=2.28765692.1750602280.1538397390-459409917.1521646598";

                System.Net.WebClient webClient = new System.Net.WebClient();
                webClient.DownloadFile(address, saveFileDialog1.FileName);
            }

            Autodesk.Revit.DB.Family family = null;
            using (Transaction tx = new Transaction(doc))
            {
                tx.Start("Load Family");
                if (doc.LoadFamily(saveFileDialog1.FileName, out family))
                {
                    String name = family.Name;
                    TaskDialog.Show("Revit", "Family file " + name + " has been loaded " );
                }
                else
                {
                    TaskDialog.Show("Revit", "Can't load the family file or already exists.");
                }
                tx.Commit();
            }

            if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
            {
                return Result.Cancelled;
            }
        }

        // Show the dialog.
        using (pickForm selectionForm = new pickForm(commandData))
        {
            result = selectionForm.ShowDialog();
        }
    }

    return Result.Succeeded;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everytime you call `saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog()` the dialog is opened. You need to store the result of the call for later checks:

```
if (result == DialogResult.Retry)
{
    System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog();
    saveFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = Convert.ToString(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
    saveFileDialog1.FileName = "test";
    saveFileDialog1.Filter = "Family Files (*.rfa)|*.rfa|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
    saveFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 1;

    // store result of the dialog
    var dialogResult = saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog();

    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
    {
      // ...
    }

    // ...

    // compare the result without opening the dialog again.
    if (dialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
        return Result.Cancelled;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily use `if ... else` statement for this like below :

```
System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog saveFileDialog1 = new SaveFileDialog();
if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    // your code
}
else // For Cancel
{
    return Result.Cancelled;
}
```